# Club as a Two-Handed Weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

So I'm building a two-handed weapon character in Pathfinder and was planning on using a longspear, however if I get pinned down, I want a good backup two-handed weapon. Someone suggested a club, as I can swing it as a two-handed weapon. But I can't find any information about using a club like that. Can anyone show me where that's stated?

Answer (score 2):

One-handed weapons can be used two-handed so long as they don't count as "light". When you do, the only change is that you add 1.5x your Strength modifier instead of 1x. A club is a simple one-handed melee weapon (not light), so the suggestion is sound—though I'll refrain from editorialising on whether it's the *best* choice since charop is not my forte.

[From the SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Damage):

> **Wielding a Weapon Two-Handed**
>
> When you deal damage with a weapon that you are wielding two-handed, you add 1-1/2 times your Strength bonus (Strength penalties are not multiplied). You don't get this higher Strength bonus, however, when using a light weapons with two hands.

Comment: What would you recommend, and what is Charop?

Comment: Oh please ask that as a question, I'd love to set the record straight.

Comment: @2ndGenerationCleric, SevenSidedDie: For what it’s worth, two-handing things is the best choice for melee in 3.PF from a charop perspective. There are better choices than either the club or the spear (both Simple weapons; if you have Martial proficiency those weapons are better by design, and if you don’t... well, you should as any kind of character who cares about hitting things with weapons). For instance, consider a horsechopper instead of a spear, a flail instead of a club. For that matter, if you’re going to be two-handing it anyway, just have a two-hander as backup.